# PHP: merge two arrays while keeping keys instead of reindexing?

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

How can I merge two arrays (one with string => value pairs and another with int => value pairs) while keeping the string/int keys? None of them will ever overlap (because one has only strings and the other has only integers).

Here is my current code (which doesn't work, because array_merge is re-indexing the array with integer keys):

```
// get all id vars by combining the static and dynamic
$staticIdentifications = array(
 Users::userID => "USERID",
 Users::username => "USERNAME"
);
// get the dynamic vars, formatted: varID => varName
$companyVarIdentifications = CompanyVars::getIdentificationVarsFriendly($_SESSION['companyID']);
// merge the static and dynamic vars (*** BUT KEEP THE INT INDICES ***)
$idVars = array_merge($staticIdentifications, $companyVarIdentifications);
```

Comment: That's odd: according to the PHP doc page, array_merge *shouldn't* do that. Are the string keys actually string representations of integers?

Comment: array_merge is reindexing my second array.
ie. it is changing the array from
`array( 123 => "VALUE123" )` to `array( 0 => "VALUE123" )`

Comment: hmm, that is interesting.  I suppose that the PHP documentation could be a little unclear on that point.  It says what will happen if *all* of the arrays have numeric keys, but it doesn't specifically say what will happen if they don't.

Comment: maybe not 2 years ago.  But in 2012, the documentation is Crystal clear on this point.

Comment: Actually, [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) is still not crystal clear.  "Numeric" actually includes a string with all digits (PHP 5.3.3).  `assert(array(0=>0,1=>1) === array_merge(array('9'=>0), array('9'=>1)))`

Answer (score 644, accepted):

You can simply 'add' the arrays:

```
>> $a = array(1, 2, 3);
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 3,
)
>> $b = array("a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3)
array (
  'a' => 1,
  'b' => 2,
  'c' => 3,
)
>> $a + $b
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 3,
  'a' => 1,
  'b' => 2,
  'c' => 3,
)
```

Comment: Be VERY careful with this!  The + operator is not an addition, it's a union.  If the keys don't overlap then all is good, but if they do...

Comment: In case anyone wonders 'what if they DO overlap?' : php.net: "The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored."

Comment: @DarioFumagalli Wonderful! I can't imagine how you got that result. I couldn't reproduce it in my environment. I would love to see the code you have used to produce that result. I guess you must be using some strange or old version of PHP.

Comment: @DarioFumagalli I don't know if I'm misunderstanding or if it's just changed since 2016, but at this point in time, the operation `print_r([2 => 56] + [2 => 30]);` yields `Array
(
    [2] => 56
)`. So, it's keeping the left hand side as specified. This is as of PHP 7.1.19, running on https://repl.it.

Answer (score 87):

Considering that you have

```
$replaced = array('1' => 'value1', '4' => 'value4');
$replacement = array('4' => 'value2', '6' => 'value3');
```

Doing `$merge = $replacement + $replaced;` will output:

```
Array('4' => 'value2', '6' => 'value3', '1' => 'value1');
```

The first array from sum will have values in the final output.

Doing `$merge = $replaced + $replacement;` will output:

```
Array('1' => 'value1', '4' => 'value4', '6' => 'value3');
```

Comment: To sum up, when adding 2 arrays, values from the first override values from the second.

Comment: I thought the second will override the first. :)

Comment: Exactly. That's why I couldn't use `$allValues += $newValues;`.

Comment: Doing `$merge = $replacement + $replaced;` will output: `Array ( [4] => value2 [6] => value3 [1] => value1 )`

Answer (score 54):

I just want to add another possibility of doing a merge while keeping keys.

Besides adding key/values to existing arrays using the `+` sign you could do an `array_replace`.

```php
$a = array(
    'foo'  => 'bar',
    'some' => 'string',
    'me'   => 'is original'
);
$b = array(
    42   => 'answer to the life and everything',
    1337 => 'leet',
    'me' => 'is overridden'
);

$merged = array_replace($a, $b);
```

The result will be:

```
$merged = array(
    'foo'  => 'bar',
    'some' => 'string',
    'me'   => 'is overridden',
    42     => 'answer to the life and everything',
    1337   => 'leet'
);
```

Same keys will be overwritten by the latter array.
There is also an `array_replace_recursive`, which do this for subarrays, too.

[Live example on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/i2Aee)

Answer (score 3):

Two arrays can be easily added or union without chaning their original indexing by **+** operator. This will be very help full in laravel and codeigniter select dropdown.

```
 $empty_option = array(
         ''=>'Select Option'
          );

 $option_list = array(
          1=>'Red',
          2=>'White',
          3=>'Green',
         );

  $arr_option = $empty_option + $option_list;
```

Output will be :

```
$arr_option = array(
   ''=>'Select Option'
   1=>'Red',
   2=>'White',
   3=>'Green',
 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try array_replace_recursive or array_replace functions

```
$a = array('userID' => 1, 'username'=> 2);
array (
  userID => 1,
  username => 2
)
$b = array('userID' => 1, 'companyID' => 3);
array (
  'userID' => 1,
  'companyID' => 3
)
$c = array_replace_recursive($a,$b);
array (
  userID => 1,
  username => 2,
  companyID => 3
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php

Answer (score 2):

The OP.'s requirement is to preserve keys (keep keys) and not overlap (I think *overwrite*). In some cases such as numeric keys it is possible but if string keys it seems to be not possible.

If you use `array_merge()` the numeric keys will always re-index or renumbered.

If you use `array_replace()`, `array_replace_recursive()` it will be overlap or overwrite from the right to the left. The value with the same key on first array will be replaced with second array.

If you use `$array1 + $array2` as the comment was mentioned, if the keys are same then it will keep the value from first array but drop the second array.

#### Custom function.

Here is my function that I just wrote to work on the same requirements. You are free to use for any purpose.

```php
/**
 * Array custom merge. Preserve indexed array key (numbers) but overwrite string key (same as PHP's `array_merge()` function).
 * 
 * If the another array key is string, it will be overwrite the first array.<br>
 * If the another array key is integer, it will be add to first array depend on duplicated key or not. 
 * If it is not duplicate key with the first, the key will be preserve and add to the first array.
 * If it is duplicated then it will be re-index the number append to the first array.
 *
 * @param array $array1 The first array is main array.
 * @param array ...$arrays The another arrays to merge with the first.
 * @return array Return merged array.
 */
function arrayCustomMerge(array $array1, array ...$arrays): array
{
    foreach ($arrays as $additionalArray) {
        foreach ($additionalArray as $key => $item) {
            if (is_string($key)) {
                // if associative array.
                // item on the right will always overwrite on the left.
                $array1[$key] = $item;
            } elseif (is_int($key) && !array_key_exists($key, $array1)) {
                // if key is number. this should be indexed array.
                // and if array 1 is not already has this key.
                // add this array with the key preserved to array 1.
                $array1[$key] = $item;
            } else {
                // if anything else...
                // get all keys from array 1 (numbers only).
                $array1Keys = array_filter(array_keys($array1), 'is_int');
                // next key index = get max array key number + 1.
                $nextKeyIndex = (intval(max($array1Keys)) + 1);
                unset($array1Keys);
                // set array with the next key index.
                $array1[$nextKeyIndex] = $item;
                unset($nextKeyIndex);
            }
        }// endforeach; $additionalArray
        unset($item, $key);
    }// endforeach;
    unset($additionalArray);

    return $array1;
}// arrayCustomMerge
```

#### Testing.

```php
<?php
$array1 = [
    'cat', 
    'bear', 
    'fruitred' => 'apple',
    3 => 'dog',
    null => 'null',
];
$array2 = [
    1 => 'polar bear',
    20 => 'monkey',
    'fruitred' => 'strawberry',
    'fruityellow' => 'banana',
    null => 'another null',
];

// require `arrayCustomMerge()` function here.

function printDebug($message)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($message);
    echo '</pre>' . PHP_EOL;
}

echo 'array1: <br>';
printDebug($array1);
echo 'array2: <br>';
printDebug($array2);


echo PHP_EOL . '<hr>' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;


echo 'arrayCustomMerge:<br>';
$merged = arrayCustomMerge($array1, $array2);
printDebug($merged);


assert($merged[0] == 'cat', 'array key 0 should be \'cat\'');
assert($merged[1] == 'bear', 'array key 1 should be \'bear\'');
assert($merged['fruitred'] == 'strawberry', 'array key \'fruitred\' should be \'strawberry\'');
assert($merged[3] == 'dog', 'array key 3 should be \'dog\'');
assert(array_search('another null', $merged) !== false, '\'another null\' should be merged.');
assert(array_search('polar bear', $merged) !== false, '\'polar bear\' should be merged.');
assert($merged[20] == 'monkey', 'array key 20 should be \'monkey\'');
assert($merged['fruityellow'] == 'banana', 'array key \'fruityellow\' should be \'banana\'');
```

##### The results.

```
array1:

Array
(
    [0] => cat
    [1] => bear
    [fruitred] => apple
    [3] => dog
    [] => null
)

array2:

Array
(
    [1] => polar bear
    [20] => monkey
    [fruitred] => strawberry
    [fruityellow] => banana
    [] => another null
)

---
arrayCustomMerge:

Array
(
    [0] => cat
    [1] => bear
    [fruitred] => strawberry
    [3] => dog
    [] => another null
    [4] => polar bear
    [20] => monkey
    [fruityellow] => banana
)
```