# array_merge with indexes

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php 

$one = array(11 => 'a', 12 => 'b', 13 => 'c');
$two = array(14 => 'd', 15 => 'e');

print_r(array_merge($one, $two));
```

this return me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
    [4] => e
)
```

i would like receive:

```
Array
(
    [11] => a
    [12] => b
    [13] => c
    [14] => d
    [15] => e
)
```

How can i merge two array with indexes? Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: merge two arrays while keeping keys instead of reindexing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292044/php-merge-two-arrays-while-keeping-keys-instead-of-reindexing)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is a possible solution.

```
$one = array(11 => 'a', 12 => 'b', 13 => 'c');
$two = array(14 => 'd', 15 => 'e');

function array_merge_values()
{
  $args = func_get_args();

  $result = $args[0];
  for ($_ = 1; $_ < count($args); $_++)
    foreach ($args[$_] as $key => $value)
    {
      if (array_key_exists($key,$result))
        $result[$key] += $value;
      else
        $result[$key] = $value;
    }
  return $result;
}

var_dump(array_merge_values($one,$two));
```

Output

```
array (size=5)
  11 => string 'a' (length=1)
  12 => string 'b' (length=1)
  13 => string 'c' (length=1)
  14 => string 'd' (length=1)
  15 => string 'e' (length=1)
```

Using print_r

```
Array
(
 [11] => a
 [12] => b
 [13] => c
 [14] => d
 [15] => e
)
```

Answer (score 6):

Arrays with numeric keys will have their keys discarded by `array_merge`. Instead, use the `+` operator instead of `array_merge`:

```
print_r $one + $two;
```

This produces:

```
Array
(
    [11] => a
    [12] => b
    [13] => c
    [14] => d
    [15] => e
)
```

Alternatively, use string keys instead of numeric keys.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried?

`$three = $one + $two;`

This should preserve the keys