# How to merge array recursive in php while retaining their index names

Tags: php, arrays

I've been searching and haven't found an answer yet to my question.

Say I want to create a menu out of three or more arrays, but I don't what elements will those arrays have.

I have something like this:

```
$arr1 = array(
   'design' => 'Link 1'
);

$arr2 = array(
   'development' => 'Link 2'
);

$arr3 = array(
   'design' => 'Link 3',
   'seo' => 'Link 4'
);
```

What can I do to turn those three arrays into this:

```
$final_array = array(
   'development' => 'Link 2',
   'seo' => 'Link 4',
   'design' => array(
         '0' => 'Link 1',
         '1' => 'Link 3'
     ),
);
```

Comment: See this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292044/php-merge-two-arrays-while-keeping-keys-instead-of-reindexing

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[array_merge_recursive()](http://php.net/array_merge_recursive)

```
$arr1 = array(
   'design' => 'Link 1'
);

$arr2 = array(
   'development' => 'Link 2'
);

$arr3 = array(
   'design' => 'Link 3',
   'seo' => 'Link 4'
);

$newarr = array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
print_r($newarr);
```