# Select2 kartik number value change to index value

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2, yii2-model

I have data like this: 
[image]

I use these data to fill the select2 kartik combobox, this is my yii2 code,

```
echo \kartik\widgets\Select2::widget([
                                'attribute' => 'pembuatSoal_id',
                                'model' => $model,
                                'data' => array_merge(["" => ""], \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\ViewUsernameGuru::find()->all(), "uname", "nama")),
                                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Pilih Guru...', 'id' => 'guru-id', 'class' => "form-control"],
                                'pluginOptions' => [
                                    'allowClear' => true,
                                    'theme' => \kartik\widgets\Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP
                                ],
                            ]);
```

**uname** field as the value of the select2 and nama as the display value. but the result is like this:
[image]

But when The value of uname field is number, select2 automaticly change with the array index of select2 items.

Hope some body give me the solve.

Thanks.

Comment: what `array_merge(["" => ""],` does?

Comment: Yes --> 'data' => array_merge(["" => ""], \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\ViewUsernameGuru::find()->all(), "uname", "nama")),. Did you know how to fix this?

Comment: you do not need to use `array_merge(["" => ""]`. Because arrayHelper creates an array.

Comment: `kd_preg` is Primary Key?

Comment: array_merge for what exactly?

Comment: thats work, i remove the array_merge.. did you know whats for the array_merge?

Comment: it is used for merge two array. for more detail: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: ok then don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: thanks for the downvote for hmmm nothing....
I pointed you to your mistake and getting a downvote...

Comment: sorry, just now i upvote your comment. i dont understand your solution before you edit your post.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  echo \kartik\widgets\Select2::widget([
                            'attribute' => 'pembuatSoal_id',
                            'model' => $model,
                            'data' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\ViewUsernameGuru::find()->all(), "uname", "nama")),
                            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Pilih Guru...', 'id' => 'guru-id', 'class' => "form-control"],
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                'allowClear' => true,
                                'theme' => \kartik\widgets\Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP
                            ],
                        ]);
```

find it [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/52278-kartik-select2-not-select-corretly/):

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the array_merge. Why do you use it because you have the option "allowClear" = true to allow an empty selection?

If you remove the array_merge the indexes won't be changed.

Just add this to allow an empty selection and give it a name.

```
'filterWidgetOptions'=>[
            'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
 ],
'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => \Yii::t('app', 'Any Entry')],
```

i tested the settings on a filter but the settings for the normal widget are similar:

```
'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Any entry'],
'pluginOptions' => [
    'allowClear' => true
],
```

works perfectly for me...
so in your case it is just

```
echo \kartik\widgets\Select2::widget([
'attribute' => 'pembuatSoal_id',
'model' => $model,
'data' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\ViewUsernameGuru::find()->all(), "uname", "nama"),
'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Pilih Guru...', 'id' => 'guru-id', 'class' => "form-control"],
'pluginOptions' => [
    'allowClear' => true,
    'theme' => \kartik\widgets\Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP
],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned the problem truly is in `array_merge` which reindexes numeric arrays, numeric strings too, following results in same in this case

```
[9 => 'foo'] 
['9' => 'foo']
```

I believe desired functionality was to have appearance of "normal" select tag with ability to select "empty" first option which sets empty value on select.

I kept searching and found simple solution which is to do addition of arrays

```
['' => 'Select value...'] + [0 => false, 1 => true]
```

With empty first option element, setting should not contain `placeholder`, because it does not display it in option list, rather us it as option name. 
`allowClear` may be set to false, or leave it out as it is default state

resulting in:

```
echo \kartik\widgets\Select2::widget([
    'attribute' => 'pembuatSoal_id',
    'model' => $model,
    'data' => (["" => "Pilih Guru..."] + \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\ViewUsernameGuru::find()->all(), "uname", "nama")),
    'options' => ['id' => 'guru-id', 'class' => "form-control"],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => false, // false is default so could be left out
        'theme' => \kartik\widgets\Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
        'dropdownAutoWidth' => 'true', // to autocalculate width of selection list
    ],
]);
```

source: [PHP: merge two arrays while keeping keys instead of reindexing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292044/php-merge-two-arrays-while-keeping-keys-instead-of-reindexing)