# How to merge multiple Associative Arrays into one?

Tags: php, arrays, json, merge, associative

how can I merge this assoc arrays to one which will have the array(title, description)? GetContent function sort of data to my requirements.

```
  function getContent($data) {
        $tabs = $data->result->data->tab;    
        $type = findByType($tabs,'content');
            $content = array(); 
            foreach ($type->unified_content->item as $item) { 
                if($item->type->name == 'header') {
                    $content[] = array(
                        'title' => $item->text
                    );   
                } else {
                    $content[] = array(
                        'description' => $item->text
                    );
                }   
            }
            return $content;           
    }
```

vardump of foreach result, how can i merge title + description:

```
array(1) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(13) "Test článku"
}
array(1) {
  ["description"]=>
  string(20) "Nový článek test."
}
array(1) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(15) "Test článku 2"
}
array(1) {
  ["description"]=>
  string(22) "Nový článek test 2."
}
array(1) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(15) "Test článku 3"
}
array(1) {
  ["description"]=>
  string(22) "Nový článek test 3."
}
```

Comment: Would you show us the 2 arrays to be merged?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: merge two arrays while keeping keys instead of reindexing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292044/php-merge-two-arrays-while-keeping-keys-instead-of-reindexing)

Comment: Don't forget the good olde array `+` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you content have strict order, you can use a temp array to store the `title` and `description` like this,

```
foreach ($type->unified_content->item as $item) { 
    if($item->type->name == 'header') {
        $arr = [];
        $arr['title'] = $item->text;
    } else {
        $arr['description'] = $item->text;
        $content[] = $arr;
    }   
}
```

If not, you need to merge the array.

Comment: Thanks very much :))

Answer (score 0):

you can user array_merge

such as

```
foreach ($type->unified_content->item as $item) { 
                if($item->type->name == 'header') {
                    $content = array_merge($content,array(
                        'title' => $item->text
                    ));   
                } else {
                    $content = array_merge($content,array(
                        'description' => $item->text
                    ));
                }   
            }
```

Comment: Its bad, because the result is only last array:string(15) "Test článku 3"
string(22) "Nový článek test 3."

Answer (score 0):

You can store **title** and **description** in one array and pass it to your **$content** array.

**Replace this:**

```
foreach ($type->unified_content->item as $item) { 
    if($item->type->name == 'header') {
        $content[] = array(
            'title' => $item->text
        );   
    } else {
        $content[] = array(
            'description' => $item->text
        );
    }   
}
```

**With this:**

```
 $i = 0;
 $content_temp = array();
 foreach ($type->unified_content->item as $item) { 
    if($item->type->name == 'header') {
        $content_temp['title'] = $item->text;   
    } else {
        $content_temp['description'] = $item->text
    }   
    $i++;
    if($i % 2 == 0){
       $content[] = $content_temp;
    }
}
```

**The Whole Code:**

```
function getContent($data) {
    $tabs = $data->result->data->tab;    
    $type = findByType($tabs,'content');
    $content = array(); 
    $i = 0;
    $content_temp = array();
    foreach ($type->unified_content->item as $item) { 
        if($item->type->name == 'header') {
            $content_temp['title'] = $item->text;   
        } else {
            $content_temp['description'] = $item->text
        }   
        $i++;
        if($i % 2 == 0){
           $content[] = $content_temp;
        }
    }
    return $content;           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

array_merge() is more efficient but there are a couple of options:

```
$array1 = array("id1" => "value1");

$array2 = array("id2" => "value2", "id3" => "value3", "id4" => "value4");

$array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2/*, $arrayN, $arrayN*/);
$array4 = $array1 + $array2;

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($array3);
var_dump($array4);
echo '</pre>';
```