# array_push using index and random inserting into another array

Tags: php

I have two arrays like

```
$first = 
Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 2
  [2] => 3
  [3] => 4
  [4] => 5
  [5] => 6
)

$second = 

Array
(
  [0] => apples
  [1] => organges
  [2] => bananas
  [3] => peaches
)
```

But, I want to push the second array elements into the first array by index.
    like

```
$result = 
Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => apples
  [2] => 2
  [3] => organges
  [4] => 3
  [5] => 4
  [6] => peaches
  [7] => 5
  [8] => 6
)
```

without changing the first elements order.help me please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: merge two arrays while keeping keys instead of reindexing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292044/php-merge-two-arrays-while-keeping-keys-instead-of-reindexing)

Comment: No.That's not my requirement

Comment: I want to push second array elements in random into the first array like the result array

Comment: @Chris I don't think that's a good duplicate, but I do think the question is too broad or unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, make a simple loop:

```
$result = [];
for($i=0; $i < count($first); $i++) {
    if(isset($first[$i])){$result[] = $first[$i];}
    if(isset($second[$i])){$result[] = $second[$i];}
}
```

If your array have variable size, compare their size first and do the loop with the bigger count.

**EDIT:**

Then taking in account you want to conserve their respective order, but merge randomly the arrays you could twist the previous code that way:

```
$result = [];
for($i=0; $i < count($first); $i++) {
    if(rand(0,1)) {
        if(isset($first[$i])){$result[] = $first[$i];}
        if(isset($second[$i])){$result[] = $second[$i];}
    } else {
        if(isset($second[$i])){$result[] = $second[$i];}
        if(isset($first[$i])){$result[] = $first[$i];}
    }
}
```

I admit it's very weird and twisted and I'm sure something more optimized could be made (it's done quickly), but, the question itself is weird xD
I hope it will help :)

**EDIT 2:**

In fact the first edit will only alternate A/B, for a full random solution and still respecting the respective order of both arrays:

```
$result = [];
$end=count($first) + count($second);
$a=0;
$b=0;
for($i=0; $i < $end; $i++ {
    if(rand(0,1)) {
        if(isset($first[$a])) {
            $result[] = $first[$a];
            $a++;
        } elseif (isset($second[$b])) {
            $result[] = $second[$b];
            $b++;
        }
    } else {
        if(isset($second[$b])) {
            $result[] = $second[$b];
            $b++;
        } elseif (isset($first[$a])) {
            $result[] = $first[$a];
            $a++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP wants the 2nd array fixed with the first array at random; "_I want to push second array elements in random into the first array like the result array_"

Comment: @WizardNx Nice. But, I want to change the index everytime

Comment: Oh, if I understand well, you want to alternate the source array but always in an incremental way, is that correct ?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton check the edits :) I think you will have your job done