# Merge associated array in php

Tags: php, arrays

How I merge two array including the keys, below array structure available with requirement, can any one help for this:

```
$a1=array('533532'=>array('token'=>'token','tripboardrefid'=>'tripboardrefid'));

$a2=array('533179'=>array('token'=>'token','tripboardrefid'=>'tripboardrefid'));

print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));
```

**Getting this structure:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [token] => token
            [tripboardrefid] => tripboardrefid
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [token] => token
            [tripboardrefid] => tripboardrefid
        )

)
```

**Need this structure:**

```
Array
(
    [533179] => Array
        (
            [token] => token
            [tripboardrefid] => tripboardrefid
        )
    [533532] => Array
        (
            [token] => token
            [tripboardrefid] => tripboardrefid
            
        )

)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: merge two arrays while keeping keys instead of reindexing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292044/php-merge-two-arrays-while-keeping-keys-instead-of-reindexing)

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` notation to get the merged state with preserved keys.

```
print_r($a1 + $a2);
```

will print

```
Array
(
    [533532] => Array
        (
            [token] => token
            [tripboardrefid] => tripboardrefid
        )

    [533179] => Array
        (
            [token] => token
            [tripboardrefid] => tripboardrefid
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_replace()` function:

```
array_replace($a1, $a2);
```